# Is there a security risk in exposing the session id in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, session, session-cookies

I'm working on a token authentication implementation in Rails 4, where the user's session cookie value is encrypted. Contained in the encrypted cookie is the user's session id (standard Rails 4 sessions).

As part of the token implementation, would it be considered a security risk if the session id were to be disclosed to the browser as an attribute of the token?

The session id will not be used as part of the token authentication process. In fact, forget for a moment that this has anything to do with token authentication.

**The question is: is there a security risk in exposing the unencrypted session id to the browser in a Rails 4 application?**

My says no, it's not a risk, because a nefarious user would not be able to maliciously construct an encrypted session cookie value, fooling the server into thinking he had a session id that was faked (at least not without access to the app's secret key).

Even if a hacker were to fake a session id, I'm not sure how it would help them, as the session id is totally random (to my understanding), and we use a cookie based store, so a change in value would have little impact on the user.

Am I right?

Comment: what'd stop someone from hijacking the session by simply stealing the entire cookie?

Comment: We use SSL in production, so we're reasonably safe from sniffers and proxies, but there are certainly other ways to steal an entire cookie. However, I'm not trying to solve that problem today.